# How to enable exception handling in mingw

Tags: c++, exception, build, qmake, mingw32

I am new to Mingw and C++ programming. I am trying to build a C++ project but getting following error.

> error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable.

Where I need to pass this -fexceptions parameter. When I am trying

> mingw32-make -fexceptions

I am getting follwoing error.

> mingw32-make: exceptions: No such file or directory

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding `-fexceptions` to the `CXXFLAGS` in your makefile instead of passing it as a command line argument?

Comment: Actually, its a QT project and make file has been generated using qmake. So, I need to modify the generated make file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Qt, add "exceptions" to the CONFIG variable in your project file (the *.pro file):

```
CONFIG += exceptions
```

This should take care of passing the correct compiler flags.

In any event, do not modify the generated Makefile. With Qt's qmake, the Makefile is just an auto-generated file.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using straight g++ from the command line, you should do:

```
g++ -fexceptions ...rest of command...
```

If you're using Makefiles, add it to CXXFLAGS (and then just build with `make` as usual):

```
# in your Makefile
CXXFLAGS := -fexceptions
...rest of your makefile...
```

The reason you get the "No such file or directory" error is because `-f` is an option for `make` which specifies the file to use, so when you pass `-fexceptions` to `make` it says "`-f` means he wants to use the following file "`exceptions`"... let me try and find a file named "exceptions"" and then, of course, it errors out when it can't find a file by that name.

The `CXXFLAGS` variable in your Makefile get passed to your compiler as flags/options, and is where you should stick any extra compiler flags (like `-fexceptions`).

**Edit**: If you're using `qmake`, try adding `CONFIG += exceptions` to your project file.