# Qt with opencv exception handling error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5

I have been able to successfully integrate opencv with Qt using the following tutorial:

[How to link opencv in QtCreator and use Qt library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library)

However, When I try to write line `#include "opencv/cv.h` in my .cpp file, qt throws me an error:

```
D:\opencv\opencv_bin\install\include\opencv2\flann\saving.h:113: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
     throw FLANNException("Invalid index file, cannot read");
                                                           ^
```

I am not sure if this is a qt problem or an opencv installation problem.

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = cube4
QT += 3d
SOURCES = cubeview.cpp main.cpp \
    haptics.cpp
HEADERS = cubeview.h \
    haptics.h \
    src/haptics.h \
    src/adll.h \
    src/afuncs.h \
    src/atypes.h \
    src/avars.h \
    src/glut.h \
    src/StdAfx.h \
    hdl/hdl.h \
    hdl/hdlConstants.h \
    hdl/hdlErrors.h \
    hdl/hdlExports.h \
    hdlu/hdlu.h \
    hdlu/hdluExports.h
HEADERS += \
    Widget.h
RESOURCES = cube.qrc

win32:LIBS += -LD:\\opencv\\opencv_bin\\bin \
    libopencv_core248d \
    libopencv_highgui248d \
    libopencv_imgproc248d \
    libopencv_features2d248d \
    libopencv_calib3d248d \


win32: INCLUDEPATH +="D:/opencv/opencv_bin/install/include"
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? is it gnu compiler?

Comment: I am using mingw compiler

Comment: you need to enable exceptions. Read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401719/how-to-enable-exception-handling-in-mingw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks iHarob. The solution was to add "exceptions" to the CONFIG variable in your project file (the *.pro file):

CONFIG += exceptions
This takes care of passing the correct compiler flags. The answer can be found here:
[How to enable exception handling in mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401719/how-to-enable-exception-handling-in-mingw)